# Best countries for PhD with good funding

Tags: phd, funding

I am interested in applying for Ph.D. in the Molecular biology field. However, I'm not sure which countries offer the best Ph.D. programs. I'm looking for good funding and a reasonable cost of living (in that particular country).  Can anyone guide me, please? Thank you.

Comment: So, the quality of education and research is not in your list?

Comment: Or future employment prospects? You need to do your research...

Comment: sweden and maybe south africa

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov Surely I'm looking for good quality of education and research. That is what I meant when I said "best Ph.D. programs." :)

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the Nordic countries, Netherlands, or Switzerland. All PhD students are employed full-time as essentially research assistants, get a reasonable salary (close to national median salary), and all those countries have high quality research, good universities, and excellent employment prospects.